# JSON Array without the key?

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, syntax

I am calling a webservice using jQuery/AJAX which returns a string array (string[]).

This is my response:

```
{"GetTagsResult":["acceleration","aktantmodellen","ampere","analyse","analyseeksempel","atmosfæren","best practice","boganmeldelse","brændtrekanten","cellemembran"]}
```

I want to get the list out in a variable, so I only operate on the list and not the "GetTagsResult" key name.

This is my call:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myabtags").tagit({
            tagSource: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags",
                    datatype: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {},
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            removeConfirmation: true

        });
    });
```

I have tried the following things on response(data) line:

- response(data.d)
- response(data.value)
- response(data[0].value)

But nothing helps.

I want to get the following out in the variable instead:

```
         ["acceleration","aktantmodellen","ampere","analyse","analyseeksempel","atmosfæren", "best practice","boganmeldelse","brændtrekanten","cellemembran"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You array is in

```
data["GetTagsResult"]
```

You may also get it with

```
data.GetTagsResult
```

So you may call

```
response(data.GetTagsResult);
```

This MDN guide might help : [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Thanks so much... ! :) I will accept as an answer in 9 minutes (SO tells me)